# I have an array of mp3 links for sounds. i am trying to use .map to show a button for each sound that plays the sound onClick

Tags: reactjs, list, audio

as the title says i am trying to use buttons to play the sounds from an array of animals.

```
<div>{dieren.map((dier:Dier) =>{
const audio = new Audio(dier.geluid)
return <div>
           <div>{dier.dier}</div>
           <button onClick={audio.play}>maak geluid</button>
       </div>})}
</div>
```

But no sounds are playing at all

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what problem you are facing here, but one problem I see here for sure is that the handler for onClick will run no matter whether you click it or not. Instead of writing it like you have written it, you should try one of the following two methods:

***Method 1: Arrow Functions***
Replace the onClick of your Button with the following:

```
onClick={() => audio.play}
```

***Method 2: Passing Function Reference***
Inside your functional component, add the following code:

```
const playAudioOnClick = (audio) => {
    audio.play;
}
```

Replace the onClick of your Button with the following:

```
onClick={(audio) => playAudioOnClick(audio)}
```

Comment: the problem is that no sound plays at all. even after trying your fixes.

Comment: You may want to try audio.play() instead.

Comment: still no sound. i'm not shure where the problem lies

Comment: Are you using a library/package for audio, if yes, can you share the link to its docs.

Comment: i am using nothing but React in a typescript template

Comment: What type is your dier.geluid, the parameter you pass into the constructor?

Comment: I am not so well-versed with the audio element in HTML, but while researching, I found this YouTube video. Thought you might be able to make use of it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NgVlAscdcA

Comment: dier.geluid is a link(string) that links to an mp3